# How can I determine whether a card being clicked on is ON TOP OF or below another card?

Tags: python, object, pygame, coordinates, overlap

I'm trying to make a card game in Python, using PyGame. It will be like a **52-card-pickup-game**. As you can imagine, most card games do not involve cards fully or partially sitting on top of other cards.  It's either cards laid out in some order, or dragging and dropping a card (that wasn't sitting on top of or lying below another card) to another location.  If I am trying to remove a card beneath one or more other cards, then I should have to remove those pieces first.  This is boggling my mind.

The only things I can see at the moment are:

- two or more cards may share coordinates.
- the center spots for each card are closer when the cards are more directly overlapping one another, and the same spots are further apart when the cards are covering less of one another
- if I could map a set of coordinates (x1, x2, y1, y2) to id's, then I might be able to more uniquely identify each card in a list or something

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could assign every card a "z-order" number (3rd dimension).  Then when a click matches more than one card, find the one with the lowest z-order, and that identifies it as the upper card.  Of course you need to maintain the z-ordering as cards are moved around.  It may be good enough just to store your "pile" of cards in a list, and use that to keep z-order.

Comment: This is in the direction I want to go, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to separate the UI layer from your logical layer. Calculating based on the center points of cards where they are on your game board as well as which is on top sounds very cumbersome. While the cards may be directly on top of each other or overlap by half the cards width, the basic logic is this, as far as I understood it from your question: you can only move the top-most card.

Let's assume you have four places on the game board where you can put down cards - these will be our "stacks" of cards from which you can pick or put another card on top. All four stacks (S1, S2, S3, S4) *can* include numerous cards (A1, A2, A3, ...), but could also be empty.

**UI Layer:**
For each stack, decide how you want to display them in a specific way (overlapping by 50%, by 100%, etc). If you click on the stack, the top most card gets automatically selected and you may have some animation (e.g. drag-and-drop). To get the "content" of the card, we look to our "Order"-Layer.

**"Order"-Layer:**
We need not only to keep track of which card is on top, but also the order of the underlying cards.  I would suggest using lists for this. Since you will be having multiple "stacks" of cards on different positions on the playing field, it might even be useful to create a "Stack" class which has all the functionality you need to interact with a stack of cards. This way, you can create an instance of the "Stack"-class for each possible area where cards can be placed on the playing field.

Example:

```
import random
class Stack():   

    def __init__(showing=True, overlap=100):
        self.cards = ['A2', 'A4', 'A10', 'A1'] 
        self.overlap = overlap
        self.showing = True # do the cards face upward or are the contents hidden?
    
    def get_top_card_of_stack_one(self):
        return self.cards.pop()  # pop removes and returns the first element of a list
    
    def put_card_on_top_of_stack_one(self, card):
        self.cards.insert(0, card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def display_stack(self)
         if overlap = 100: # 100% overlap
               pass # test for self.showing and display the stack
         elif overlap = 50: # the cards are overlapping by 50% of their width, and you see how many there are
               pass # test for self.showing and display the stack
```

As an example:
You have six stacks of cards, e.g. you create six instances of the class with different parameters.

- the player's hand (showing = True, overlap = 30%)
- the other players' hands (3x) (showing = False, overlap = 30%)
- one draw-stack(showing = False, overlap = 100%) - from which player's draw new cards
- one play-stack (showing = True, overlap = 100%) - where player's put the cards they play

[image]

Comment: What I'm looking for is the effect of a "52 card pickup" type of game.  About as random in positioning of cards as you can get.  That's what I'm after.  Laying things out as you are suggesting is rather easy.